# How do I correct my dog peeing inside and drinking her urine?

Tags: toilet-training, urination, shelter

My healthy, 3 year old rescue (Doberman Pinscher) has always had issues holding her pee. We’ve had her for 8 months and sometimes even if we take her out to pee right before bed, she’ll pee her bed just a couple hours into the night. In this case and in any other case where she pees in the house, she will drink the urine. We think she may have been from a puppy mill because she also has had issues eating her poop and has always had issues peeing in her bed/crate while I’ve heard that’s very abnormal for most dogs. We’ve had her tested for uti/bladder issues and nothing.

We try to limit her water intake before bed, but don’t know what else we can do to prevent it. Happens maybe 1-2 times a month. Every time we catch her we stop her and take her outside to finish (she always pees a bunch more once taken out) but would like to implement something to stop her before her bed gets soiled. Or any tips to help her learn to hold it? The 2 AM laundry is getting a little old.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't think you could somehow train her to not need to pee during the night. Usually you would train a puppy to hold their pee longer and longer during nighttime, until they get used to it. If your dog wasn't trained that way as a puppy, it may not work anymore as an adult.

The reason why I don't think it's possible is that you write

> Every time we catch her we stop her and take her outside to finish (she always pees a bunch more once taken out)...

That basically means that her body is used to process liquids and produce urine at night. That happens completely unconsciously and no amount of training will change her. There's the same phenomenon in humans as well: some can sleep the whole night but others wake up and have to pee every night. Not drinking anything in the evening doesn't change how your body works.

A better solution might be absorbant pads intended for puppies that are not completely house trained. Just put one in her bed, or maybe two if her bed is bigger than a pad. If she "has an accident" only once or twice a month, the cost involved is low.

Another alternative could be to train her to pee in a place you can clean easily, like a walk-in shower. I'm not completely sure *how* to best tell her that peeing there is ok and judging from her behavior I'm not sure she wouldn't drink it also. It might be worth a try to establish a command like "go pee" whenever she relieves herself and then lead her into the shower and tell her to "go pee" there. Encourage and reward her excessively when she actually pees there to reinforce the new rule. Make sure the door is opened at night.